# Rails association getting complex to understand

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many, model-associations

I am bit old but still new to Rails and in my learning orocess I have got stucked in a point where I can't figure out how can I make association between two entities.

> **So here is the background of app.
> There is a user and ad entity.
> User can create many ads and an ad belongs to one user so its a pretty straightforward association of one to many.
> Now the confusion is that I want to add a feature where users can add ads to his favorities.
> So one user can have multiple fav_ads and one ad has multiple likers.
> Its also straight forward many to many association but there is already has many ads in user model so if I even user has many ads through fav_ads where fav_ads is a bridge table and vise versa then user.ads will give me what? I now there must a way fir this scenario as its pretty common in webapps and database but don't know how to do it in rails.**

Comment: If you can only fav an ad you already like you can add a column to that table `boolean :favourited`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a join table with one column for user_id and one column for ad_id.
This table might be called "user_ad_like".

For the migration you use `create_join_table` ([docs)](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_join_table)

Something like

```rb
class UserAdLike < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_join_table(:users, :ads, table_name: "user_ad_like"
  end
end
```

And for the models you'll use has_and_belongs_to_many  ([docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many))

```rb
class Ad
    # Likes  (ad.likers)
    has_and_belongs_to_many :likers, class_name: 'User', join_table: "user_ad_like"
    # Creator (ad.user)
    belongs_to :user
end
class User
    # Liked ads (user.liked_ads)
    has_and_belongs_to_many :liked_ads, class_name: 'Ad', join_table: "user_ad_like"
    # Ads create (user.ads)
    has_many :ads
end
```

You'll then have

1. `user.ads` which gives you created ads
2. `user.liked_ads` which gives you liked ads
3. `ad.person` which gives you the creator
4. `ad.likers` which gives you all the users who have liked the ad.